# add an image in some option using angular ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, ng-options

I try a trick but it didn't work as expected

I want to add a picture at some options create in a `select ng-options`

i try something like this

```
<select size="4" ng-model="ObjDetails" class="form-control select"
ng-options="value as (value.attr + ' : ' +value.attr2 + '<img src=\'img/ro.png\' alt=\'lol\'/>') for value in objList">
</select>
```

but it display my attributes follow by `<img src=\'img/ro.png\' alt=\'lol\'/>` untreated.

I try to display an image only in some case, so i didn't want to do it in css with :after -> it would do it on all my options.

Can somebody tell me the corect way?

Comment: Not possible with a standard `select` drop-down list (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp). You would need a custom dropdown.

Comment: try ui-select module, it will help